# MongoDB Query - Subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this below

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"), 
    "main_array" : [
        {
            "cars" : [
                "BMW", 
                "Toyota"
            ], 
            "parts" : [
                990
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("yyy"), 
    "main_array" : [
        {
            "cars" : [
                "C2", 
                "BMW"
            ], 
            "parts" : [
                991, 
                123
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "cars" : [
                "Audi", 
                "Ford"
            ], 
            "parts" : [
                990
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Part - 1
I need to query the parts: 990, and return only the car array documents that as the same parts -> 990

output

```
 "cars" : [
                "Audi", 
                "Ford"
            ]
```

Part 2 - 
update the all other documents that have the same part numbers

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"), 
    "main_array" : [
        {
            "cars" : [
                "BMW", 
                "Toyota"
            ], 
            "parts" : [
                990
            ],
            "other_cars" : [[
                "Audi", 
                "Ford"
            ]]
        }
    ]
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did part 1 only get Audi and Ford but not BMW and Toyota as well?

Comment: if i find for 990, it gives me 2 documents within the array. i want only the document that has part # 990

Comment: I'm asking why `ObjectId("xxxx")` is not matched in step 1.

Comment: because its in the same document. we are searching for other sub document , that has the same part number, and the other "car" into the first sub document

Comment: Assuming object `yyy` had this format `"cars" : [
                "Audi", 
                "Ford", "BMW"`
            ], would you like BMW to be part of the update?

Comment: the data is not inserted like that. but either way, its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "main_array.parts": 990,
            "_id": {$ne: ObjectId("xxxx")} //exclude curr document
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$main_array"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "main_array.parts": 990
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$main_array.cars"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            cars: {$addToSet: "$main_array.cars"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            cars: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Part 2:
Now we just have to update the old document:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: oldDocumentID },               
   { $set: { "main_array.$[element].other_cars" : aggregationResultsArray } },
   {
       arrayFilters: [ { "element.parts": 990 } ]
   }
)
```